# Statically linked OpenGL library on Windows

Tags: c++, visual-c++

I want to get ( or build from source) OpenGL library that is statically linked to the crt on Windows.

I don't want my executable to require OPENGL32.dll.

My compiler is Visual C++ 9.

Where do I begin? The OpenGL website directs me to this wiki http://www.opengl.org/wiki/Getting_started
But that wiki tells me "In all three major desktop platforms (Linux, MacOS X, and Windows), OpenGL more or less comes with the system".
I am on Windows. Is this statement true. How do I verify this?

Comment: [Further down](http://www.opengl.org/wiki/Getting_started#Writing_an_OpenGL_Application) the page you posted, it tells you about `opengl32.lib`.

Comment: @Peter Wood I saw that. Is opengl32.lib linked to static crt? I don't want my executable to require OPENGL32.dll in order to run

Comment: Why don't you want `opengl32.dll` to be a dependency? It is included on all major Windows systems. You don't have to distribute it yourself.

Comment: If you don’t use OpenGL32.dll you will have to implement the whole of OpenGL yourself (and use some alternative system DLL to do get the result onto the screen anyway), and/or supply your own mechanism for forwarding calls to the graphics drivers (for which the Microsoft Dev Center article [_Loading an OpenGL Installable Client Driver_](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff568203.aspx) might be a starting point). Are you _sure_ this is what you want to do?

Answer (score 5):

> Statically linked OpenGL library on Windows
>
> I don't want my executable to require OPENGL32.dll.

Impossible. End of story. opengl32.dll is provided by microsoft and may be changed after each system update. So you can't static-link it - it is a system component.

You can only static link with [mesa3d](http://www.mesa3d.org/) which emulates OpenGL on CPU. However, it is not fully compliant to OpenGL, so you can get unexpected problems, and you'll still require several system dlls. (my bet is gdi32.dll) for your application. Also, performance will be very bad compared to normal OpenGL.

Answer (score 1):

I believe what you are saying is that you don't want to be forced to make your application link with the C Runtime libraries dynamically (i.e. Multithreaded DLL or Multithreaded Debug DLL in the Properties/C++/Code Generation/Runtime Library setting).

Since OpenGL is a system provided .DLL, you are still free to choose Multithreaded or Multithreaded Debug (both choices statically link to the C Runtime) for your Runtime Library when using OpenGL.